# Cannot run a simple smartsheet-python-sdk project

Tags: python

I want to connect to smartsheets and use this simple code

```
import smartsheet

# Initialize client. Uses the API token in the environment variable "SMARTSHEET_ACCESS_TOKEN"
smart = smartsheet.Smartsheet()
```

When try to run the code with below command

```
python smartsheet.py
```

I got below error.

```
(myenv) PS C:\Codes\langchain-experiments\slack> python smartsheet.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Codes\langchain-experiments\slack\smartsheet.py", line 1, in <module>
    import smartsheet
  File "C:\Codes\langchain-experiments\slack\smartsheet.py", line 4, in <module>
    smart = smartsheet.Smartsheet()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'smartsheet' has no attribute 'Smartsheet' (most likely due to a circular import). Did you mean: 'smartsheet'?
```

It is the same code in example project [here](https://github.com/smartsheet-samples/python-read-write-sheet)  and it is not working at all

I am using smartsheet-python-sdk-3.0.2 with python 3.11.4

Comment: Your file `smartsheet.py` is shadowing `smartsheet`. `import smartsheet` is importing `smartsheet.py`, not the library package you want. Change its name to something else.

Comment: Thank you I just noticed after I submit my question and came to answer. But thanks a lot anyways.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Brian61354270](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11082165/brian61354270) I changed my py file name to something different than smartsheet.py and it worked.